# How to pack/unpack a number into a 4-byte array in PHP?

Tags: php

I'd like to convert a number into a 4-byte array for sending through a socket. For example, here is what I did in ruby:

```
> xmlLength = 260
 => 260 
> [xmlLength].pack("L").unpack("CCCC")
 => [4, 1, 0, 0]
```

How this can be done in PHP?

Tried:

```
print_r(unpack("CCCC", pack("L", 260)));
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [CCC] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var_dump(unpack('c*', pack('i', 260)));
// array(4) { [1] => int(4) [2] => int(1) [3] => int(0) [4] => int(0) }
```